# From public data, I cannot determine how the engagement heat-map interval provided by youtube data is computed

Tags: youtube, heatmap

Youtube provides viewer heat-maps for its videos. There are 100 points regardless of the length of the video. Does each point represent the aggregate over some small time-interval around that point or the entire interval in which the particular heat-map point lies?

I have a hard time from the available information determining which one is the case.